# How to treat Disposables correct in project with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

When I started to use **RxSwift** I used to create `BaseViewController` and extend it with all my controllers where I use **RxSwift**. 
The code of BaseViewController.swift:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
var mSubscriptions: CompositeDisposable?

func addSubscription(subscription: Disposable){
    if(mSubscriptions == nil){
        mSubscriptions = CompositeDisposable()
    }
    if let mSub = mSubscriptions{
        mSub.addDisposable(subscription)
    }
}

func unsubscribeAll(){
    if let mSub = mSubscriptions{
        mSub.dispose()
        mSubscriptions = nil
    }

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeAll()
}

deinit{
    unsubscribeAll()
}
}
```

And I use addSubscription(:_) method everywhere in my child controllers. For example a piece of code from:

```
class TasksViewController: BaseViewController{
   overrided func viewWillAppear(){
       //...
     var subscribe = dataLoader.load(requestNetwork, dataManager: taskDataManager)
    .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: queue))
    .subscribe({ (event) -> Void in
        //...

    })
    addSubscription(subscribe!)
   }
}
```

What if I do not use BaseViewController and just create an instance of `DisposeBag()` in every controller and add all my subscriptions to that disposeBag? And how should I treat Disposables correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just add a `let disposeBag = DisposeBag()` property to your view controllers. Adding `Disposable`s to that is all you need to do.  `DisposeBag` is like a `CompositeDisposeBag` that will `dispose` the `Disposable`s for you when `DisposeBag` is deallocated (which will happen when the `UIViewController` is deallocated).  There's no need to manage it manually.

However, you can continue to use a subclass if you wanted:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

And then to use it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Observable.just(42)
        .subscribeNext { i in
            print(i)
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

This is in fact what `ViewController` base class does in `RxExample`:

[property in ViewController](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/f4ef06e88d50e25d480c79f705af4fef82a1a0a9/RxExample/RxExample/ViewController.swift#L31)

[Usage in a subclass](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/f4ef06e88d50e25d480c79f705af4fef82a1a0a9/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/Numbers/NumbersViewController.swift#L31)

If you're actually wanting to be able to deallocate everything manually (as you were doing with `unsubscribeAll`), then you can just set the `disposeBag` to `nil` or a new `DisposeBag` so that it gets deallocated: `disposeBag = DisposeBag()` or `disposeBag = nil`.

Comment: Thank u very much. Perhaps you can advice some tutorials about RxSwift? Because there is few information on this subject.

Comment: Yea definitely. Check out the example app in the RxSwift repo called "RxExample". Just run it in the simulator. Also, the RxSwift repo has some great Playground pages with small examples of most operators.

Comment: @Marina This serie it's an excellent introduction to RxSwift in 4 post http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/ios/rxswift-by-examples-1-the-basics/